# Why do these two methods to determine the number of print columns behave differently?

Tags: perl, unicode, printing

With these Unicode ranges [Unicode::GCString](https://metacpan.org/module/Unicode%3a%3aGCString)'s`columns` returns the number of print columns while `mbswidth` from [Text::CharWidth](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCharWidth) doesn't.
To they behave differently because they use different databases?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use open qw(:std :utf8);
use Text::CharWidth qw(mbswidth);  # 0.04
use Unicode::GCString;             # 2012.10 

for my $hex ( 0x0378 .. 0xd7ff, 0xfa2e .. 0xfdcf, 0xfdfe .. 0xfff8 ) {
    my $chr = chr $hex;
    if ( mbswidth( $chr ) == -1 ) { # -1 invalid data
        my $gcs = Unicode::GCString->new( $chr );
        my $width = $gcs->columns;
        printf "%04x - %d  :  %s\n", $hex, $width, $chr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Text::CharWidth` uses the C library function `wcwidth` which depends on the OS and current locale. `Unicode::GCString` uses the [sombok](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linefold/) library. The latter seems to be regularly updated to the latest Unicode versions, so I'd consider it to be accurate.