# How can I determine how many columns a string will occupy when printed to the console?

Tags: string, perl, unicode, console

This question is restricted to strings devoid of whitespace,
written intentionally for a human to read them.

I don't care about NUL or other characters that one would not find in a piece of text set down for human consumption.

Also, I don't care about "pathological" cases such as

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;
use feature 'say';
say 'dog', "\r", 'rat';
say 'a', "\b", 'z';
```

This question would be useful, for instance, for generating nicely centered lines of text, when the text is not all ASCII.

In the Perl script below, we look first at strings that take up 1 column, then 2 columns, 3 columns, etc.

As we see from running this code, neither the number of bytes, nor the length of an array created by splitting a string at `\B`, reliably tells us how many columns a string or a character will take up when printed. Is there a way to get this number?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use strict; use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while(<DATA>)
{
    say '------------------------------------------';
    print;
    $_=~s/\s//g;
    my@array=split /\B/,$_;
    say length $_,' bytes, ',scalar@array,' components';
}

__DATA__
a
é
ø
ü
α 
ά
∩
⊃
≈
≠
好
üb
üü
dog
Voß
café
Schwiizertüütsch
```

Comment: [`use Text::CharWidth qw(mbswidth);`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CharWidth)

Comment: How about `A[backspace]B`? Is that one, two or three columns?

Comment: @OldGeezer I am not worried about pathological cases. Here is another pathological case: `perl -e 'use feature "say"; say "dog", "\r", "rat"; ' `. This takes up three columns. I want a tool for figuring out how to position text in the console---information my code prints into the console or into a file, for me to read. The text my code produces is, by design, not pathological, but it does contain non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @ThomasDickey is it fair to ask how long `use Text::CharWidth qw(mbswidth);` has been around and how well tested? Years ago, I installed `use IPC::Run qw( run );` only to have my code break recently at that point, even after I reinstalled it. Code that I relied on every day. So I try not to build stuff into my code that requires special installation.

Comment: The CPAN page says 2003.  Debian has a [package](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?dist=unstable;package=libtext-charwidth-perl) for it.  fwiw, I use it in [`git-stats`](https://invisible-island.net/scripts/readme.html#item:git-stats)

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't deal with *fullwidth* characters, and wouldn't be useful to me.

Comment: This answers your question: [Why do these two methods to determine the number of print columns behave differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359514/why-do-these-two-methods-to-determine-the-number-of-print-columns-behave-differe)

Comment: @ThomasDickey "_The accepted answer doesn't deal with fullwidth characters_" -- fixed.  (Will rewrite nicely.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of columns used by a terminal to print text is directly determined from the number of "characters" printed, where each may take 0, 1, or 2 columns to print.

Those are the *logical* Unicode characters, [extended grapheme clusters](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode#Extended-Grapheme-Clusters-%28Logical-characters%29).  They may be character sequences, often a base character and its [combining diacritical marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks) (accents), or may have a single codepoint, but represent one character from the particular writing system/language.

What is needed then is to break the input into characters in a way that respects Unicode and find out how many columns each needs. (Well, or use a library that does that.)

One way to look into the width is by testing with regex the `East_Asian_Width` property, with `\p{East_Asian_Width=Wide}` or `\p{EA=W}`.  See [perluniprops](https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops) (+ [perluniintro](https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniintro), [perlunicode](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode)).

Or, go to the core module [Unicode::UCD](https://perldoc.perl.org/Unicode::UCD), which interfaces the Unicode Character Database and has *all* properties.

The values can be: Neutral (not East Asian), Wide, Ambiguous, Narrow, Fullwidth, and Halfwidth -- what always resolves into two, narrow or wide, depending on context. See all detail in the Unicode Standard Annex for East Asian Width, [UAX #11](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr11/tr11-39.html#:%7E:text=East%20Asian%20Ambiguous%20(A)%3A,to%20further%20resolve%20their%20width.), or see the list in the `perluniprops` linked above, which also shows how often they are found; the first three listed are represented incomparably more often than the rest.

The odd man out in that list is [Ambiguous](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr11/tr11-39.html#Ambiguous), which can be either wide or narrow, depending on the context of its use (whether it is East Asian or not), what includes all kind of detail; see the link.  Given the seeming need in this question, I'll leave that out for now and treat it as narrow. Then the only property value that requires 2 columns would be `Wide`.

An example

```
use warnings;
use strict; 
use feature 'say';
use List::Util qw(sum);

use utf8;
use open qw(:std :encoding(UTF-8));

my @w = qw(a é ø ü α ά ∩ ⊃ ≈ ≠ 好 üb üü dog Voß café Schwiizertüütsch);

foreach my $word (@w) {
    my $cols = sum map { /\p{EA=W}/ ? 2 : 1 } split '', $word;
    say "$word needs $cols";    
}
```

If we were to use the character database then we'd also need the character's codepoint, for example

```
use Unicode::UCD;

for my $ucp (unpack 'W', $word) {
   my $eaw = charprop($ucp, "East_Asian_Width");
   say $eaw;
}
```

This produces the names listed above.

We also need to enable Unicode support for the program (which is where the sample program from the question fails): The [utf8 pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/utf8) is there since the  source file itself has Unicode characters in it while the [open pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/open) takes care of the standard streams.

Recall that all this leaves out the `Ambiguous` ones, ie. we take them all to be narrow, which in general isn't correct.

The easiest way to improve on this is to use a library, [Unicode::GCString](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::GCString), and with it things turn almost trivial

```
use Unicode::GCString;

foreach my $word (@w) {
    say "$word needs ", 
        Unicode::GCString->new($word)->columns, " columns";
}
```

While this library is clearly put together thoughfully and is reputable, this does come with a caveat.  By its latest meaningful update, of a number of years ago, the library uses Unicode Standard 8.0.0 (as stated in [Unicode::LineBreak](https://metacpan.org/dist/Unicode-LineBreak/view/lib/Unicode/LineBreak.pod) which it uses), which is badly out of date and this may cause errors (see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70834053/4653379)).

That is a nit in comparison with the fact that the manual approach doesn't even address the context of Ambiguous width.  But an important issue in the context of this question is that this is an external module and which comes with a need for a C library ([sombok](https://github.com/hatukanezumi/sombok)), and which appears to not be updated any more.

Thanks to tchrist for bringing some of this up and thus triggering a far more detailed discussion.

---

If the intended use here does not involve Wide characters then it's pretty simple

```
while (<DATA>)
{
    s/\s//g;

    # Either of
    my @chars = split '';     
    my @egc = /(\X)/g;

    say "$_\t", 0+@chars, " chars (split), ", 0+@egc, " chars (regex, \\X)";
}
```

(The Chinese character in the provided input then won't be correct but presumably that is actually not needed in this use case.)

The `\X` is one way to [match a logical character](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash#%5CX), and also see `\b{gcb}` on the same page.  The capture `(\X)` isn't needed here since we want all that's matched, so `my @egc = /\X/g;` is fine. But it doesn't hurt and if there is more in the pattern one may need it so I put `()` in.

Please excuse my manners with `0+@ary` for array size as I'm trying to fit a line of code in display width for easier reading; by all means one should use `scalar @ary` for this.

With the addition of the pragmas above the code in the question works well, and a statement from [length](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length) I find instructive

> Returns the length in *characters* of the value of EXPR.
> ...
> Like all Perl character operations, `length` normally deals in logical characters, not physical bytes.

(original emphasis)

Thanks to Thomas Dickey for calling the omission of character width discussion in the original post.  Thanks to tchrist for comments.

Comment: Your first sentence isn't correct (Unicode characters may use 0, 1 or 2 columns).

Comment: @ThomasDickey Well, right, but it's (I thought?) _very_ rare outside of writing systems that use "pictograms" of various kinds and so I wasn't concerned at first in (what seems to be) their use case. (The Chinese character in the very example clearly needs two places.)  I guess I should see how to determine the actual number of columns and certainly amend the text in the meanwhile, what I am doing right away.  Thank you for the comment.

Comment: [To me it's always seemed better](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicook#%E2%84%9E-34:-Unicode-column-width-for-printing) to use `Unicode::GCString->new($str)->columns` to compute the columns needed. Wouldn't that be easier and more reliable?

Comment: @tchrist Indeed, and I even got a bit more of fullwidth chars with it (out of a large codepoint range I tested things with).  But the OP seemed ... cautious, to say the least, in their comments about additional libraries (I understand them), and this one even needs a C library if I recall correctly.  Then I forgot to even mention it, what I intended.  Will add, thank you  (Btw, as for "_more reliable_" -- I just don't know about that.  OK, if you say so, good to know and thank you for that info)

Comment: The reliability I was thinking of has to do with needing more context to determine how many columns that code points with the `East_Asian_Width=Ambiguous` character property work out to occupying. [Per UAX#11](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr11/tr11-39.html#:~:text=East%20Asian%20Ambiguous%20(A)%3A,to%20further%20resolve%20their%20width.): *“ED6: East Asian Ambiguous (A): All characters that can be sometimes wide and sometimes narrow. Ambiguous characters require additional information not contained in the character code to further resolve their width.”* Haven't read it lately, though.

Comment: @tchrist OK, that could be the reason that the library finds some 600 wide chars more than regex (`\p{EA=W}` only), out of its ~42K wide chars found in the range of ~56K codepoints I tested with (about a  percent in that pool).  That's helpful because `UAX#11` (thank you for the link!) says for context  "_...such as explicit markup, knowledge of the source code page, font information, or language and script identification..._" (with examples), what's not plausible to find out by hand every time.  ...

Comment: @tchrist  [cont'd]  The downside is that the lib doesn't seem maintained  -- `Unicode::LineBreak` that it uses quotes unicode standard 8.0. (Granted, that's much less of a problem than not addressing Ambiguous at all.)  I've rewritten the post (will likely edit).  Thank you for comments :)